# Calling 2 different ARest-APIs in single get Request

Tags: rest, get

I have one ARest service.
which does have 2 Resources.

```
HostName: CustomerAdminSystem.com
Operation: Get
First-ResourceName: AdminData
Second-ResourceName: CustomerData.
```

Here, Resource-1 & 2 both are totally mutually exclusive and we can definitely call them parallel & get the data.

what is the way to get such data in a single call.

I am aware of the term: Composite-APIs concept, which basically enables to call 2 different API of single service in one go.
Ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm

but as mentioned in this page:

```
 Executes a series of REST API requests in a single call. You can use enter code here the output of one request as the input to a subsequent request.
```

but we don't want to keep second call on hold until first finishes.

How can we really invoke 2 different resources in a parallel way.
any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: How you call 2 things in parallel depends on the programming language you're using.

Comment: @Evert, we are using NodeJS at client-side to call this API.

Comment: Then just do 2 requests and don't await them.